# Chrome wrongly interpret img size - bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Ok. Problem is as follow. I have rectangular icon with IMDB logo. I was trying to position it inside div but there is problem because apparently Chrome sees image as square while Safari not.

Pictures for reference:

[image: Chrome]
[image: Safari]

Is it a bug? Why it's not corrected if both browsers run on the same engine?
Friend told me solution "put it in some wrapper, set its width and then set img width to 100%" but it's not working :(

Code:
`<div class="something">
<img src="file.png">
</div>`

Comment: I'm not sure but posting a code example would probably help you get better help

Comment: This screenshots shows screen from Web Inspector. Code is the same in both cases.